# My character has trouble running, he can only walk

Tags: borderlands-2

For some reason every time I try to run by using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (and <kbd>W</kbd>) for example, my character just stops moving. I can't get him to run while walking by pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after the <kbd>W</kbd> key is pressed. If I press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key first and then the <kbd>W</kbd> key, the character just jerks as if attempting to start the run, but then comes to a full stop. Repeating this just results in sort of jerks forward.

This seems to be some sort of bug. I can get around this for now, by jumping forward first, then mid-jump pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key so that when he lands I already have <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> pressed. Then he starts running after completing the jump.

I am wondering if some config video quality setting could be causing this problem. Does anyone know of a solution to this to allow my character to run normally as he should.

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware problem.

Comment: I have had a similar problem in another Unreal 3 engine based game. It was resolved when I lowered a video setting (maybe something to do with shadow, but I don't remember for sure). So, it's definitely an engine issue.

Comment: Does this ever happen in any other fps games where you use w and shift at the same time? Do you have any hotkey, key macro, or key repeating software running (AMD Catalyst has hotkeys)? Workaround: sprint is press and forget, so you can tap it and let go and you will sprint until you let go of W.

Comment: I am going to try with another keyboard. I do not have any software running that breaks basic Shift-W functionality. I tried "press and release" (of the shift key, while continuing to hold W), still a no go.

Comment: I've had this exact problem before now when using a PS/2 to USB keyboard adapter. Are you using one of these, by any chance? If so, try using a plain standard USB keyboard. If not, then I'm afraid I'm not sure.

Comment: on a side note, do you have any programs that uses these two keys as shortcuts? I installed a media player and its shortcut is `ctrl+shift` and it takes priority. so imagine my agony when i want to `ctrl+shift` to select lines in microsoft word and it just keep repeating the same song on my media player.

Comment: Never experienced a problem like this. Try rebinding your keys.

Answer (score 1):

Its either a bug or your keys are acting up.